# Holiday diary with LaTeX

Tags: packages, book-design

I want to write a diary of my holidays. I thought to use `part` to subdivide the diary by years, `chapter` to subdivide by holidays (places) and `section` to subdivide by days. This works quite well, but I think a package created for keep a diary would be better. My problem is that I want to add some (from two to five) photos each day and floating objects are not ideal for this type of document.

Can someone tell me how better keep a diary with LaTeX? Is there any package?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty long holiday if you need to section it by years. Lucky you `=)`

Comment: @Jake In fact I wanted to create a "book" with ALL my holidays, starting by now. ; )

Comment: Simply don't use flaots! You can have pictures with captions without floats. This has been discussed many times. Search for `\captionof{figure}{Caption of picture}` or `\usepackage{capt-of}` or `\usepackage{caption}`

Comment: `\documentclass{holiday}\usepackage{duck}` ... sorry :-D

Comment: There's a typo in the question title: LaTex should be LaTeX. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid floats, one option, as explained Martin H, is do not use floats at all.

But other is to use floats with the option "here": `[h]` or `[h!]` o even the more strict `[H]` (is this case need the package `float`) and even change the placement rules (see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)).

The advantage is that if finally place "just here" was not really such a great idea (specially if you later need add memorable happenings that were forgotten, ruining all the "good placements" below) it is easier allow a little float flexibility (`[h]` instead `[H]` for example, see note below), or a lot more flexible(`[tbph]`), or change placements rules in the preamble, instead of modify the hard written code.

On the other hand, from what you say, I think a document class `book` without any special package is perfect for your travel journal, unless you explain what other features are looking for. However, you can use also a `article` class and use `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` and even numbered or not `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` for a more compact format. Depends on what you like. It's your decision.

**Note**: Contrary to what one might think, `h` option is flexible since it is changed to `ht` when cannot be placed in the page, as happen in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\lipsum[2]
\textcolor{blue}{\lipsum[2]} 

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\fbox{Imagine some graphic here}
\caption{Wanted between blue and red text, but here is better}
\end{figure} 

\textcolor{red}{\lipsum[4]} 
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

If even then any rule is violated in the next page (more than 2 figures in the top, fill more than 70% of the height, etc.) the figure (and following also) wait for the top page and so on, unless the end of the article or the chapter is reach and then all  unprocessed floats are flushed. Left several figures at the end might be acceptable or not, but when there are many figures awaiting their turn there a high risk of compilation error ("*Too many unprocessed floats*") that must be arranged with `\clearpage` commands here and there, changing LaTeX rules as `\setcounter{topnumber}{3}` or, better, allowing more floats options.

Comment: Using `[h]` alone is not recommended: if the figure can't be placed it will block all the following ones, resulting in every float being printed at the end of the chapter.

Comment: @egred. Agreed. Little flexibility is troublesome, but really `[h]` is never alone (see added note) and this problem  could happen even allowing more options.